# A unique word: Says Grandpa

Tags: word, no-computers, word-property

"Very interesting word", said Grandpa. "Could be the only word with this property"

"What property?", I asked

> "At least 9 letters long and first four letters are same as the last
>   four letters!
>
> It is kind of a medical word and starts with a name.
>
> And son, it is not a hyphenated word, nor it is a intentionally made
>   double word like abracadabra or muckamuck. No cheat words like that!"

"Where did you find it?" I asked

"On the Net. Someone generated a list for me. But this one was the only non made up word. It is in the MW dictionary"

Really?

Comment: Just to check - first 4 letters same as last 4 letters *in the same order*, right?

Comment: Right @Stiv  like muckamuck

Comment: Does the fact that Grandpa says "starts with a name" rather than "starts and ends with a name" indicate that the name in question is more than 4 letters?

Comment: @DEEM Perhaps you should [edit] that into the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Grandpa's obscure medical word might be:

> **URICOSURIC** - a word used to describe "*substances that increase the excretion of uric acid in the urine, thus reducing the concentration of uric acid in blood plasma*" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uricosuric))
>
>  Note that it begins with the Israeli first name 'Uri'.

I hope Grandpa's alright...

> If "someone generated a list for me" is a euphemism for "asking for a friend" he may well have read this word on the side of his bottle of [gout medication](https://www.cardiosmart.org/healthwise/hw66/700/hw66700)!

Comment: do you think this is the only real word (not made up or hyphenated) that has this property? Any way to find out?

Comment: But this is a 10 letters word @Stiv, isn't it?

Comment: "at least 9 letters long" @stratos

Comment: I missed the "at least" part.

Comment: @DEEM I imagine someone (not me!) might be able to write a program that checks the first 4 letters against the last 4 letters for all words in a dictionary, limiting the results to those with 9 letters or more. It would then require an examination by eye to see if any fit your other criteria, but I imagine there can't be *that* many words on such a list (and many may be considered nonsense words and thus disqualified...). Unfortunately that would be beyond my skills!

Comment: It's not beyond mine. I find at least the following in one (fairly large) word list, besides the one here: archmonarch, kingmaking, archphylarch, archpatriarch, overhover, shipmanship, outshouts, overcover, overlover. Most of those seem a bit iffy, but "kingmaking" is obviously OK. Not a medical term, though it does start with a (sur)name.

Comment: Or you could go to Qat and put in "ABA;|A|=4" and in its default dictionary it will find a bunch of silly echo-y ones but also "singularising" and "galengale".

Comment: (And also "overcover". With its maximum-size wordlist, which admittedly contains all sorts of rather absurd things, it also has the ones I mentioned above. I didn't notice any other "reasonable" words in its output.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan "**Noti**fica**tion**" - the rule doesn't say that they need to be in the same order!

Comment: @Chronocidal But the comment below it does! (I had to clarify that myself...)

Comment: @Stiv A pity - otherwise, we could just use "rotavator" (longest single-word palindrome in the English language - the rule applies for *any* length of substring from 1 to 9!)

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan  kingmaking is not in MW dictionary though